# How to handle certificate OS pop up in Selenium python? I tried pyAutoGUI, but it didn't work

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, certificate

I work with Selenium on python to navigate at Google-Chrome. 
At some point in my application SSL certificate pops up (It suppose to be here, I have a legit certificate, I just need to press 'Ok'). If I understand it right, it is not a browser's popup, but an OS popup. Thus, selenium can't handle it. To solve the problem I tried pyautogui that is supposed to handle OS popups.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(url)  # fetching the page
res = driver.\ 
    execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
```

At this point Certificate Window pops up. I try to click on it with pyautogui:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, duration = 0.5)
```

But the problem is that when the certificate popup window appears, the scrip stops and pyautogui can't move the mouse to click on the certification. When I click manually 'Ok' on the window, pyautogui starts to work. But I need it to click 'Ok' automatically. 
Does anyone know how to handle this script freeze? 
Thanks!

Comment: Separate thread?

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you should first understand *why* the certificate warning appears. If it's a self-signed certificate that you trust, add it to the system certificate store. If it needs to be renewed, renew it. Et cetera.

Comment: I do trust the certificate, it supposed to be here. I just need to click on it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 separated threads actually worked! thanks for the idea. Posting it as a separate answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to solve it with two separated threads (thanks @wizzwizz4 for the idea):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

def manage_os_popup():
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, duration = 0.5)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click()

my_thread = threading.Thread(target = manage_os_popup)
my_thread.start()

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(url)
res = driver.\ 
    execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
```